# Create multiple indexes in a transaction using C# Mongodb strongly typed driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using the official C# MongoDb strongly typed driver version 2.7.0-beta0001 to interact with MongoDB.

What I am trying to do is to create multiple indexes in a single transaction but I always get "Message  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Even if I didn't use the transactions by removing the session variable, I also get the same exception.

Here is my code:

```
var client = new MongoClient(ConnectionString);

var database = client.GetDatabase(DatabaseName);

var Coupons = database.GetCollection<Coupon>("Coupons");

var Books = database.GetCollection<Book>("Books");

var session = await database.Client.StartSessionAsync();
session.StartTransaction();

try {

     var options = new CreateIndexOptions() { Unique = true };

     var couponIndex = new IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<Coupon>().Ascending(c => c.CouponNumber);
     var couponIndexModel = new CreateIndexModel<Coupon>(couponIndex, options);
     await Coupons.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(session, couponIndexModel);//Exception happens at this line

     var bookIndex = new IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<Book>().Ascending(c => c.BookNumber);
     var bookIndexModel = new CreateIndexModel<Book>(bookIndex, options);
     await Books.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(session, bookIndexModel);

     await session.CommitTransactionAsync();
} catch (Exception ex) {
     await session.AbortTransactionAsync();

     Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
}
```

Here are the exception details:-

```
Message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Source  "MongoDB.Driver"

StackTrace  "at MongoDB.Driver.MongoIndexManagerBase`1.ToCreateManyIndexesOptions(CreateOneIndexOptions options)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoIndexManagerBase`1.CreateOneAsync(IClientSessionHandle session, CreateIndexModel`1 model, CreateOneIndexOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

TargetSite  {MongoDB.Driver.CreateManyIndexesOptions ToCreateManyIndexesOptions(MongoDB.Driver.CreateOneIndexOptions)}  System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}

{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoIndexManagerBase`1.ToCreateManyIndexesOptions(CreateOneIndexOptions options)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoIndexManagerBase`1.CreateOneAsync(IClientSessionHandle session, CreateIndexModel`1 model, CreateOneIndexOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am trying to do is to create multiple indexes in a single transaction

Operations that affect the database catalog, such as creating or dropping a collection or an index, are not allowed in multi-document transactions.

See also [MongoDB Transactions and CRUD Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/#transactions-and-crud-operations) for more information.

[MongoDB commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/) supported in transactions are:

- [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate)
- [count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/count/#dbcmd.count)
- [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/distinct/#dbcmd.distinct)
- [geoSearch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoSearch/#dbcmd.geoSearch)
- [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/#dbcmd.find)
- [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#dbcmd.findAndModify)
- [getMore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getMore/#dbcmd.getMore)
- [insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/insert/#dbcmd.insert)
- [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/#dbcmd.update) (including multi-update)
- [delete](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/delete/#dbcmd.delete) (including multi-delete)